# Users follow others model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, relationship

In my Rails application I'm letting users to follow companies and everything works fine, but actually I want that users to be able to follow a company from a job page

my job model is

```
belongs_to :company
```

and my company model is

```
has_many :jobs
```

so in a job view page, that belongs to a company, I'm trying with this:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @job.company)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

but I'm getting this error:

> Couldn't find Company with 'id'=#

for `@company = Company.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])`

So I'm wondering what is the fault in my code? and I appreciate any help

Comment: Can you please explain your usage of the `actionscript-3` tag?

Comment: it is a fault however thank you i will edit the tags even if i think the title is explanatory

Comment: Just provide `@job.company.id` in place `@job.company`.  
As: `<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(followed_id: @job.company.id)) do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
followed_id: @job.company
```

but you need to use

```
followed_id: @job.company.id
```

Otherwise it is apples and oranges.